# How we can mount amazon s3 on amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-s3

I would like to know, how we can connect s3 and ec2 or how we can access data from s3 through ec2.

Answer (score 18):

There are no special APIs in EC2 to access data stored in S3. You use the same methods [documented](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/s3/) and you can use the [standard SDKs](http://aws.amazon.com/code).

One thing is definitely better: there are no data transfer charges when accessing S3 from an EC2 instance.

Comment: It has been 6 years. Is there a way now?

Answer (score 10):

Same way you'd access S3 from any other server - HTTP request, [mount S3 as a filesystem](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon), etc.