# Amazon ec2 and s3

Tags: amazon-s3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How we can mount amazon s3 on amazon ec2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150786/how-we-can-mount-amazon-s3-on-amazon-ec2)

Hi,

I have one Amazon ec2 account and Amazon s3 account. Now I want to store some files in s3 and want to retrieve these files for some computation in ec2. my question is how we can upload files into the buckets of s3 and how we can access these files from ec2 . how we can make a connection between these two.how we locate s3?

Comment: Duplicate of [How we can mount amazon s3 on amazon ec2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150786/how-we-can-mount-amazon-s3-on-amazon-ec2), from 20 minutes ago. Don't repost questions.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is done through standard HTTP methods: GET, PUT, etc.

Amazon has produced some very clear documentation explaining how to work with S3: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/

There are also open source libraries published for today's mainstream languages (PHP, .NET, Java, Ruby, Python, etc). These can greatly reduce your development time, however it helps to read throught the AWS docs to know what's happening behind the scenes (especially when something breaks).